# NodeJS Returning data from nested promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I am fairly new to promises and could so with any pointers on how to get this to work.
None of the variations I have tried have managed to trigger the final success/error callbacks, or have managed to but haven't returned the data.

```
export function getData(start, end, tagSet){
    let data = new dataSet();
    // Initial setup to work out what data to fetch

    return database.Read(config).then(function (results) {
        // Process the results.......
        return data;
    }, function (errCode) {
        // Throw Error
    });
}

// Call the function, triggered by a seperate event
getData.then(function(data){
    //Success !!
    
},function(err){
    //Failure!!
    
});
```

I have also tried setting up a new promise

```
export function getData(start, end, tagSet){
    let data = new dataSet();
    // Initial setup to work out what data to fetch

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        database.Read(config).then(function (results) {
            // Process the results.......
            // Update data
        }, function (errCode) {
            // Throw Error
        });
        return data;
    }
}
```

<s>I don't want to make the getData function blocking by using await</s>, so what is the correct way to return data from a promise inside a function?

- Edit: Typo
- Looks like I misunderstood how await works when inside a async instruction.

Comment: `getData.then(...)` you need to call getData `getData(start, end, tagSet).then(...)`

Comment: Apologies that was a typo in the question - the actual code did have that - I just accidentally misssed it when simplifying it for the question.

Comment: Then the error has to be somewhere in the code that you removed to simplify the code, because your first snippet should basically work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't return anything from promises, but instead resolve or reject a promise.

your 2nd example should look something like this

```
    export function getData(start, end, tagSet){
    let data = new dataSet();
    // Initial setup to work out what data to fetch

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        database.Read(config).then(function (results) {
            // Process the results.......
            // Update data
        }, function (errCode) {
            // Throw Error
            reject(errCode) // <-- if error happens, you reject your promise with error
        });
        resolve(data) // <<-- if there is no error, you resolve your data
    }
 }
```

then you can use

```
getData.then(function(data){
   //promise is resolved
})
.catch(function(err){
   //promise was rejected
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - the resolve looks to be what I was looking for, however I have given the code you suggested a try and the getData promise is resolving before the database.Read().then() has run.

Comment: No. First, in your example, `resolve(data)` is called before `database.Read(config)` has finished. It will not wait for the `results` to be processed and it won't wait to see if an error occured. It will always and immediately `resolve(data)`. Second, the entire approach is an antipattern. There is no need to create a `new Promise`, because `database.Read(config)` already returns a Promise.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the solution I wanted was to set the function as async and use an await.

```
export async function getData(start, end, tagSet){
    let data = new dataSet();
    // Initial setup to work out what data to fetch

    await database.Read(config).then(function (results) {
        // Process the results.......
        // update data
    }, function (errCode) {
        // Throw Error
    });
    
    return data;
}

// Call the function, triggered by a seperate event
getData().then(function(data){
    // Success !!
    // data has been completed here
},function(err){
    // Failure!!
    
});
```

This results in the returned data being completed before being the getData().then() is triggered.